# error in Button Jiggle algorithm

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i have impletemented a button jiggle animation.where pressing a button wobbles ,but the problem is the animation does'nt stop and getting an error in [self.layer removeAllAnimations];
below is the code;

```
 -(IBAction)button1Clicked:(id)sender
 {
UIButton *no1 =sender;
output= [self answerCheck:no1.titleLabel.text];
self.label.text=output;
[self enableOptions:NO];
[self loadingView];
[self startJiggling:2];

 }
- (void)startJiggling:(NSInteger)count
{

    CGAffineTransform leftWobble = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians( kAnimationRotateDeg * (count%2 ? +1 : -1 ) ));
    CGAffineTransform rightWobble = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians( kAnimationRotateDeg * (count%2 ? -1 : +1 ) ));
    CGAffineTransform moveTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(rightWobble, -kAnimationTranslateX, -kAnimationTranslateY);
    CGAffineTransform conCatTransform = CGAffineTransformConcat(rightWobble, moveTransform);

    self.btnOption1.transform = leftWobble;  // starting point

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1
                          delay:(count * 0.08)
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                     animations:^{ self.btnOption1.transform = conCatTransform; }
                     completion:nil];
 [self stopJiggling];
}

-(void)stopJiggling 
{
    [self.btnOption1.layer removeAllAnimations];
    self.btnOption1.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;   // Set it straight 
}
```

Comment: property layer not found...i want to know the use of layer

Comment: Well then, you're obviously calling this from a class that does not have a property called `layer`. What class are you subclassing? Is this a view controller of some kind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're setting the animation on `self.btnOption1`, so you would need to remove it from `self.btnOption1`:

```
- (void)stopJiggling {
    [self.btnOption1.layer removeAllAnimations];
    self.btnOption1.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
}
```

but in fact if you just set the `transform` property of the button again, outside of an animation block, it will remove the animation:

```
- (void)stopJiggling {
    self.btnOption1.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
}
```

(This worked in my test project.)

#### Update:

I notice that you're starting the animation with a delay, and you're calling `stopJiggling` *immediately* after you call `animateWithDuration:...`.  I don't know why you're using a delay or why you're calling `stopJiggling` immediately.

I created a test case to match your code:

```
@implementation ViewController {
    __unsafe_unretained IBOutlet UIButton *btnOption1;
}

- (IBAction)startJiggling {
    btnOption1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-.1);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.1 delay:2 * 0.08 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse animations:^{
        btnOption1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(.1);
    } completion:nil];
    [self stopJiggling];
}

- (void)stopJiggling {
    [btnOption1.layer removeAllAnimations];
    btnOption1.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
}

@end
```

I hooked up my `btnOption1` ivar to a button, and connected the button to the `startJiggling` method.  With the code as shown, clicking the button does nothing, because the animation is removed immediately after it is added.  If I comment out the `removeAllAnimations` message, clicking the button makes the button start jiggling and it jiggles forever.  I tested on the iPhone 4.3 simulator, the iPhone 5.0 simulator, the iPhone 5.1 simulator, and my iPhone 4S running iOS 5.1.

So, I could not reproduce your problem.  Sending `removeAllAnimations` removes the animation in my test.

I suspect that you just want the animation to repeat twice and then stop (since you have an argument named `count` and you're passing 2).  If that's what you want to do, you can do it like this:

```
- (IBAction)startJiggling {
    btnOption1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-.1);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.1 delay:2 * 0.08 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse animations:^{
        [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:2];
        btnOption1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(.1);
    } completion:^(BOOL completed){
        btnOption1.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    }];
}
```

You set the repeat count inside the animation block using `+[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:]`, and you restore the button's transform in the completion block.

Comment: Quite right. I guess I wasn't thinking. This is the correct answer.

Comment: I changed the above answer..pls check it out..still i m not able to stop the animation..should i got to make any changes above

Comment: @user578386 You need to actually use that in your animation's `completion` argument. Just create a block that calls `[self stopJiggling]`, or just call the methods directly.

Comment: yup i called that [self stopjiggling]; but it aint stopiing

Comment: If it's not working then there's something you're not telling us.  How do you set `btnOption1`?  How do you set its target and action? Do you change it anywhere?

Comment: btnOption is an IBOutlet button..thats the place i call [start gigling]..updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Remember to import QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h to talk with layers.